# Method is called multiple times in unit tests but not in code

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I am writing unit tests to a class that uses RxJava 2. When onNext() is called on the observer I expect `onMenuLoaded()` to be called once. In code it is called successfully once. But when I test this piece in unit tests the method is invoked 3 times.

The questions are how to make it be called only once in tests and why it is called more times in tests than in the actual code.

```
//in ViewModel class, under testing
fun loadMenu() {       
        menuInteractorImpl.getMainMenu()?.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())?.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())?.subscribe(
                { items ->
                    onMenuLoaded(items)
                },
                { error ->
                    //error handling logic
                }
                )?.let { compositeDisposables.add(it) }
}
    //Test
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(MenuInteractorImpl::class, MainMenuViewModel::class)
class MainMenuViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    companion object {
        @ClassRule
        @JvmField
        val schedulers = RxImmediateSchedulerRule()
    }

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        doNothing().`when`(viewModel).startTimerToScrollViewPager()
    }

    @Test
    fun `test load menu calls onMenuLoaded when success`() {            
            val mockObservable = Observable.just(mockDataFactory.mockMenu).doOnNext {

            viewModel.onMenuLoaded(it)
        }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        Mockito.`when`(menuInteractorImpl.getMainMenu()).thenReturn(mockObservable)

        viewModel.loadMenu() //this method is called 3 times
        Mockito.verify(viewModel, times(1)).onMenuLoaded(any())
    }
```

From the logs it is shown where the method is called

```
viewModel.loadMenu();
-> at com.example.mainmenu.MainMenuViewModelTest.test load menu calls onMenuLoaded when success(MainMenuViewModelTest.kt:88)

viewModel.loadMenu();
-> at org.powermock.core.MockGateway.doMethodCall(MockGateway.java:182)

viewModel.loadMenu();
-> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Did you see the stacktrace? Was `testloadmenucalls` call same times like `loadMenu`?

Comment: @DmitroIvanov thanks for drawing my attention to the logs, I paid attention to them and it turns out that PowerMockito was calling it 2 more times through reflection and weird combination of PowerMockito and Mockito!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in accidentally combining PowerMockito spy and Mockito mock. When importing Mockito's spy the issue was resolved.

**EDIT:**
I faced the same issue again and the solution was a different one. It looks like the same cause is combining PowerMockito and Mockito. I solved it this time by adding a `doNothing` block

```
    doNothing().`when`(viewModel).myCall(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your real code is calling `onMenuLoaded(items)` in `onNext` and then your mock observable is additionally calling it from `doOnNext`.

You need to remove the `doOnNext` part of your mock observable:

```
@Test
fun `test load menu calls onMenuLoaded when success`() {            
    val mockObservable = Observable.just(mockDataFactory.mockMenu)
                                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    Mockito.`when`(menuInteractorImpl.getMainMenu()).thenReturn(mockObservable)

    viewModel.loadMenu() //this method is called 3 times
    Mockito.verify(viewModel, times(1)).onMenuLoaded(any())
}
```

Comment: you are right, I have it doubled, but when I remove it the observer hits onError (which is not relevant) but the loadMenu is still called 3 times (not 2 even)

Comment: Can you post the full ViewModel class and test class